# Python: how to turn string to int then add decimal to number

Tags: python

I have a text file which i load in python, i load the file and split the values.The text file contains the following...

```
   678John Jones          23501289100005670
   999Arthur Dudley-Smith 40000956064012300
  5789Bob Billards        04600230190048945
543780Helen W Anderson    53001945045000990
```

for example i create an array called Hours[] then append the number to it by...

```
Hours.append(int(line[26:30]))
```

doing this give the value for Hours[0] to be 2350, but i want there to be a decimal place, so it should be 23.50

I cant figure out how to do this and any help i could get would be great

Comment: Could you just divide by 100?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a floating point number:

```
Hours.append(float(line[26:30]) / 100.0)
```

Or if you're going to be dealing with large numbers, you might want to check out the decimal module.

Answer (score 1):

Take the first bit, and a dot, and the second bit:

```
>>> line = '   678John Jones          23501289100005670'
>>> line[26:28] + '.' + line[28:30]
'23.50'
```

Convert it to numeric one way:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('23.50')
Decimal('23.50')
```

If you must convert it to float, the one-trailing-zero doesn't really exist - 23.5 == 23.50, it's only there if you format it as a string and ask for a trailing zero.

```
>>> int(line[26:28]) + 0.01* int(line[28:30])
23.5

>>> '{0:0.2f}'.format(23.5)
'23.50'
```